# Nesting Gridview inside Formview breaks insert codebehind context

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a couple of GridViews in my FormView page and I am wanting to make an Insert row in the FooterRow of the Gridviews. Layout and everything is fine. However, as I'm building the codebehind for the Insert command, I'm running into a context problem. If I move the GridView outside of the FormView markup, the context errors clear up immediately.

GridView Markup

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvBFMats" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="MaterialID" DataSourceID="BFMatsSQL" OnRowCommand="gvBFMats_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commands" ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Add to Table" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
...
```

Insert Command Codebehind

```
    protected void gvBFMats_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Insert" && Page.IsValid)
        {
            BFMatsSQL.Insert();
        }
    }

    protected void BFMatsSQL_Inserting
        (object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlNewMfr =
            (DropDownList)gvBFMats.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNewMfr");
        DropDownList ddlNewThickness =
            (DropDownList)gvBFMats.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNewThickness");
        DropDownList ddlNewCore =
            (DropDownList)gvBFMats.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNewCore");
        DropDownList ddlNewSize =
            (DropDownList)gvBFMats.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNewSize");
        TextBox txtNewColor =
            (TextBox)gvBFMats.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewColor");
        TextBox txtNewQty =
            (TextBox)gvBFMats.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewQty");
        DropDownList ddlNewFinish =
            (DropDownList)gvBFMats.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNewFinish");
        TextBox txtNewExtra =
            (TextBox)gvBFMats.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewExtra");

        // Set the SQLDataSource's InsertParameters values
        e.InputParameters["MatManufacturerID"] =
            Convert.ToInt32(ddlNewMfr.SelectedValue);
        e.InputParameters["MatThicknessID"] =
            Convert.ToInt32(ddlNewThickness.SelectedValue);
        e.InputParameters["MatCoreID"] =
            Convert.ToInt32(ddlNewCore.SelectedValue);
        e.InputParameters["MatSizeID"] =
             Convert.ToInt32(ddlNewSize.SelectedValue);
        e.InputParameters["MatFinishPrePostID"] =
             Convert.ToInt32(ddlNewFinish.SelectedValue);

        string strNewColor = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNewColor.Text))
            strNewColor = txtNewColor.Text;
        e.InputParameters["MatFinishColor"] = strNewColor;

        int? intNewQty = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNewQty.Text))
            intNewQty = Convert.ToInt32(txtNewQty.Text);
        e.InputParameters["MatQty"] = intNewQty;

        string strNewExtra = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNewExtra.Text))
            strNewExtra = txtNewExtra.Text;
        e.InputParameters["MatNumExtraSheets"] = strNewExtra;

    }
```

Specifically, I get the red squiggly under the gvBFMats in the `(Control)gvBFMats.FooterRow.FindControl("Control ID");` that says "The name 'gvBFMats' does not exist in the current context." I'm only guessing that it doesn't like the call to the GridView when it's nested inside a FormView template. Is there a way to pass this context along programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about it not recognizing the name `gvBFMats` because it's embedded in a template.  Only "top-level", non-embedded controls will be treated in Code Behind as if they had been explicitly declared.  Controls declared in a template will not.  The compiler doesn't recognize those names.

There's a reason for this. Imagine you have a control called `TextBox1` in one of the `ItemTemplates` for a repeating control.  You bind it.  Your page's control tree now has dozens of controls with the ID `TextBox1`.  If you want to refer to `TextBox1`, how does it know which one you mean?

So.  What can you do in your situation?  Well, `BFMatsSQL_Inserting` and `gvBFMats_RowCommand` are both event handlers, so you can't change their signatures.

But, you can make use of them belonging to the same class, and use a module-level variable to hold the reference to `gvBFMats`.  Like this:

```
private GridView gvBFMats;
protected void gvBFMats_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    gvBFMats = [your form view].Row.FindControl("gvBFMats") as GridView;
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert" && Page.IsValid)
    {  
        BFMatsSQL.Insert();
    }
}
```

Now, `BFMatsSQL_Inserting` will be able to refer to `gvBFMats`, and it should have a value.